# Record audio from Bose S1 Pro using a Olympus WS-853

Tags: audio-recording, hardware

I need to record audio out of a [Bose S1 Pro](https://www.bose.com.au/en_au/products/speakers/portable_pa_speakers/s1_pro_system.html) using a [Olympus WS-853](https://www.amazon.com.au/gp/product/B013WBIW3K/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) audio recorder. I made the assumption I can just use a 1/4 to 3/8 adapter to hook up the line out from the Bose S1 Pro to my audio recorder, but [this site](https://toonz.ca/bose/wiki/index.php?title=S1_Pro_Line_Out_to_a_Third_Party_Device) literally says that won't work (at the bottom of the page).

[This](https://www.swamp.net.au/swamp-stereo-1-8-mini-jack-to-dual-1-4-cable?awcp=223364331&awgp=15781060611&awkw=&awct=48330344811&awpl=&gclid=CjwKCAjw0a-SBhBkEiwApljU0vCYEMTxfzIHYLoNiZAXp-nYgZ601paaMyBvjPDzm-SgQ_gBGftiuRoCOY8QAvD_BwE) looks like a cable that the site says should work, however, the bolded part just confused me:

"If the recording device has a single stereo minijack input **you will need to convert to S1 Pro System balanced mono output to an unbalanced signal.** ".

Also on the [cable site](https://www.swamp.net.au/swamp-stereo-1-8-mini-jack-to-dual-1-4-cable?awcp=223364331&awgp=15781060611&awkw=&awct=48330344811&awpl=&gclid=CjwKCAjw0a-SBhBkEiwApljU0vCYEMTxfzIHYLoNiZAXp-nYgZ601paaMyBvjPDzm-SgQ_gBGftiuRoCOY8QAvD_BwE), it says the 3.5mm is the input, whereas I will be using the 1/4" as the input, will this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make a cable. Two conductors required.

- Join 1/4" Tip to 3.5mm Tip to 3.5mm Ring
- Join 1/4" Ring to 1/4" Sleeve to 3.5mm Sleeve

Done. This will give you mono output from the Bose to dual mono input on the Olympus.